# How to get the latest artifact from artifactory with no properties

Tags: artifactory

I was using "build": "Build/LATEST" to get the latest artifact but one of the artifact I want to download does not have properties to get the build name. Is there a way to get the latest artifact by layout of the repo? I was trying to use this

```
 GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/latestVersion?g=mygroup&a=myartifactid&v=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT&repos=myrepo
```

but I don't know how to get the group id/artifact id or version.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have different versions of an artifact in a layout.

If so, you can use [Retrieve Latest Artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact)
 which will retrieve the latest artifact version by layout (you can also change the configuration to return the last created by date).

Otherwise, you can use [Item Last Modified](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemLastModified) to retrieve the item last modified at a path.

Note that you tried using [Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout) which will only get you the version of the latest artifact, but not the artifact itself.

Comment: Please could you give an example of how to use retrieve latest artifact? GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/[RELEASE]/acme-[RELEASE].jar - what do we have to replace org/acme/[RELEASE] with?

Comment: I got this working GET /api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme?lastModified. I get the latest artifact uri but I'm unsure how this can help in downloading the artifact to a specified target?